# jQuery load content when scroll to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need to do when i'm scrolling down of my page load more

```
<div class="container">
<div class="news">News 1</div>
<div class="news">News 2</div>
<div class="news">News 3</div>
<div class="news">News 4</div>
</div>
```

i have only html site, no PHP and MySQL, all news are i one page.
for example  when scroll to bottom for 500 px, load more content

Comment: I don't think you should ask this question when no effort is seen by us. We don't help lazy guys.

Comment: What you are looking for is lazy load. Google jquery lazy load. sure you will find a plugin

Comment: i find this but i need that it work for my class container and not not for <div>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237555/jquery-load-content-when-scroll-to-bottom-100px-of-page-multiple-events-fired

Answer (score 1):

I think that you would do it better with a Lazy Load plugin in Javacript.

But simpliest way to implement what you want is using Jquery following this steps:

1 - Calculating de Window Vertical size (on document ready)

```
var element = $(window).height();
```

2 - Calculating Scroll and counterweigh with the element page

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (y >= element){
      // Do stuff, like append more elements
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking for lazy load [this](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) is a good step-by-step tutorial on how to get  it on your website. I have done it on my website in no time.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code for this is:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
    var element = $(document).height();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var y = parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($(window).height());
        if (y >= element){
            $("#loader_bars").show();
            //Make post to server from last id recieved
        }
    });
});
```

Its bug free, I used all the time.....Also the lazyload the Mirakurun said is just for images

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).